# Cleaner way to pass id into jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm just wondering if there is a cleaner way to pass id into timepicker function.  Here's what I have:

JS:

```
function timedrop(id){
   $("#" + id).timepicker();
   $("#" + id).timepicker('option', { 'minTime': '9:00am', 'maxTime': 
                                      '9:00pm',    'timeFormat': 'h:i A' });
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="basicExample" onclick="timedrop(this.id);" type="text" class="time ui-timepicker-input" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: A cleaner way would be to separate your JS from your HTML (easier to maintain and track down where errors come from)

Comment: Code would be a lot simpler just using class and not worrying about ID or `onclick` and use `$('.ui-timepicker-input').timepicker({/*options object/*})`

Comment: Also, the code you have will instanciate a new timepicker on every click. You may only want to do that at page load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: **no**. That is probably the best way. But you can make your code more efficient by using custom classes(You won't have to execute the JavaScript each time):

HTML:

```
<input id="basicExample" type="text" class="time ui-timepicker-input special-time" autocomplete="off">
```

JS:

```
$('.special-time').click(function(){
    $(this).timepicker('option', { 'minTime': '9:00am', 'maxTime': 
                                          '9:00pm',    'timeFormat': 'h:i A' });
});
```

Comment: Your answer is better than mine, so I'm deleting mine.  Not to be argumentative, but as to OP's question, yours is definitely much cleaner than OP's.  It just doesn't pass the #id because it doesn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need id anywhere else, then passing `this` should work:

```
function timedrop(elem){
   $(elem).timepicker();
   $(elem).timepicker('option', { 'minTime': '9:00am', 'maxTime': 
                                      '9:00pm',    'timeFormat': 'h:i A' });
}

<input id="basicExample" onclick="timedrop(this);" type="text"
       class="time ui-timepicker-input" autocomplete="off">
```

EDIT: of course there's some sound advice given by others. My answer is only to make the code look cleaner.